# in VB.NET unsupported media type on XML-API request with CookComputing.XmlRpcV2

Tags: vb.net, xml-rpc

I have the following function in a VB.NET program that was working for a connection with an outsource system XML-API for years with no problems.

Recently, the responsible team for the specific API moved their system to another address (and probably another system) and claim that there is no change and I will just have to make a change in the address that I connect to.

I changed the address and firstly I had some connectivity problems with the new address ("An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host") and discovered that I had to compile my code to an earlier .NET Framework version in order to connect because the authentication protocol from their side was changed to TLS v1.2 instead of TLS v1.1 that they were using in the old address.

Now I get an exception “unsupported media type” from CookComputing.XmlRpcV2 when I try to communicate (fetch data) from the new API.

With some googling, I found that the specific exception has to do with content-type header of the request.

The strange thing is that using Postman I can succesfully get a response with both the old and new address using the same content-type (application/xml). The response from the API team was that their system is set to accept and produce the following content types: text/plain, text/html, and application/xml, so I don't think that the problem is with the content-type header.

Does anyone have any ideas on what else should I try ?

```
Imports CookComputing.XmlRpc
Imports System.Net

   
Public Shared Function CommunicateWithApi(ByVal pTest As Boolean,
                                          ByVal pCommand As String,
                                          ByVal pInParamsArray As ArrayList,
                                          ByRef pOutParamsArray As ArrayList,
                                          ByRef pErrorMessage As String) As Boolean
    
    
            Try
                Dim _Api = XmlRpcProxyGen.Create(Of IActionAid)()
                If pTest Then
    
                   _Api.Url = "https://test.blabla.org/servlet/B2BNK"
                Else
                    _Api.Url = "https://live.blabla.org/servlet/B2BNK"
                End If
    
    
    
                _Api.XmlEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-7")
                _Api.XmlRpcMethod = pCommand
                _Api.UseIndentation = False
                _Api.UseIntTag = True
    
                Dim pParams() As Object = pInParamsArray.ToArray
                Dim Response() As Object = {}
    
                Response = _Api.FetchData(pParams)
    
                For i As Integer = 0 To Response.Count - 1
                    pOutParamsArray.Add(Response(i))
                Next
    
                Return True
    
            Catch fex As XmlRpcFaultException
                MsgBox((String.Format("Fault Response: {0} ", fex.FaultCode)) + fex.FaultString, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
                pErrorMessage = String.Format("{0:00000000000000000000},{1}", fex.FaultCode, fex.FaultString)
                Return False
            Catch webEx As WebException
                MsgBox("WebException: " + webEx.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
                pErrorMessage = String.Format("70000000000000000000,{0}", webEx.Message)
                If webEx.Response IsNot Nothing Then
                    webEx.Response.Close()
                End If
                Return False
            Catch xmlRpcEx As XmlRpcServerException
                MsgBox("XmlRpcServerException: " + xmlRpcEx.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
                pErrorMessage = String.Format("80000000000000000000,{0}", xmlRpcEx.Message)
                Return False
            Catch defEx As Exception
                MsgBox("Exception: " + defEx.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
                pErrorMessage = String.Format("90000000000000000000,{0}", defEx.Message)
                Return False
            End Try
End Function
```

Comment: You wrote "I had to compile my code to an earlier .NET Framework" - did you mean compile it to a *later* version? Which version did you change from and to?

Comment: Yes i am sorry. I compiled to a later :-) Changed from .Net Framework 4 to .Net Framework 4.7.2